# Is cracking wifi password Halal Or Haram

Tags: halal-haram, theft

Is cracking wifi password Halal Or Haram and does it differ if the internet pckage were limited or not limited?

Comment: Why would you crack Wi-Fi password?

Comment: who's password are you cracking? Your own or someone else's. Is it with permission? Best to understand the question before giving a fatwa

Comment: to use internet for free. Some neighbor might have bought an internet package, and he has it over wifi. the Questioner is asking if he can steal the broadband? by hacking the password of wifi or not? Does it even matter to the owner if it is unlimited connection? @AbuNooh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing is haram in Islam:

> "[As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in recompense for what they earned [i.e. committed] as a deterrent [punishment] from Allah. And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise." [Quran 5:38]

You cracking the WIFI password for your use is stealing since they are paying for the internet service and not you. You are using someone else's resources that are not yours which they pay cash for. Additionally, this can also be constructed as invasion of privacy since if you are on the network you can view most of the public files on many networks that are not secured:

> "Do not spy on one another." [Quran 49:12]

Comment: How could you possibly know who's password he's talking he could have gotten permission

Comment: Look up what password cracking means. Why would someone pay/ask him to crack for them when they can easily reset it? Even then why would the OP think that would even be Haram if he has permission?

Comment: But does it the same in limited and unlimited, unlimited wouldn't hurt the owner of the internet in his package exactly when it is used for browsing only

Comment: Cracking softwares isn't spying, it's an artistic way to make an expensive material reachable for the poor.